# Dynamic commandline arguments and preloading tasks while maintaining debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing a WPF application that will be called by a third party application.  The third party app sets up some data in a database and passes a key via command line argument to the WPF application.

This is difficult to debug as the WPF application behaves differently based on different criteria in the database.

Is there a way I could create a launcher application in a separate project but same solution that would set up this data and then open the application with the command line argument needed?  I'd rather not be setting the arguments via the debug properties of the project.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I want to "Attach to Process" in Visual Studio.  But, I'd like to do it immediately, after the process is started and not delayed..

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using unit testing, which do allow running the tests in the debugger if necessary.

You can easily test a ViewModel, but Views are much harder. So this may require some redesign, but it would pay for itself in terms of reproducible test and regression cases.

Comment: Yea, I'm fully MVVM and doing good unit tests.  But, it's difficult to actually run the application and see it working without hooking it up to the third party application and losing the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly here are 2 fast ones:
1) Open a console window and start your app with chosen command line arguments.
2) Use dotnet (google for the Shell class/namespace) to do the same.

HTH

Comment: Command line wouldn't setup the data I need.  And I don't think either option would give me debugging in Visual Studio.